# Linux Networking: Command to reflect to changes made to resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking

I changed the resolv.conf in my machine. What command should I run, so that the changes will take effect.

My machine is running ubuntu 9.10.

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 5):

It should take effect right away unless you are using a dns cache daemon of some sort.